# How can I match all the rows from one table to a column in another table in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't know if the method I have in mind (which the question relates to) is the best way to arrive at the desired result, so if anyone has a better idea I'm all ears. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. Given a space-delimited set of search terms, I want to search a particular column, with consistent results regardless of the order of the terms. So e.g. "brown dog" and "dog brown" should return similar results. I have a table-valued function that takes a string and a delimiter and returns the split string as a single-column table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
    @char_array varchar(500), @delimiter char(1)
)
RETURNS 
@parsed_array table
(
    Parsed varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @parsed varchar(50), @pos int

    SET @char_array = LTRIM(RTRIM(@char_array))+ @delimiter
    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @char_array, 1)

    IF REPLACE(@char_array, @delimiter, '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        WHILE @pos > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @parsed = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@char_array, @pos - 1)))
            IF @parsed <> ''
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @parsed_array (Parsed) 
                VALUES (@parsed)
            END
            SET @char_array = RIGHT(@char_array, LEN(@char_array) - @pos)
            SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @char_array, 1)

        END
    END 
    RETURN
END
GO
```

The column I want to search is a varchar(2000). Right now I'm searching it like so:

```
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Description LIKE '%' + @searchTerm + '%'
```

But that doesn't return consistent results given the scenario I described above where multiple terms are in a different order. Is it possible to somehow join the table from the function to the column and get the desired result? Note the results should contain all rows where the Description contains **all** search terms in any order.

Comment: Wait, if you will search for "brown dog" it should return ONLY "brown dog", not "dog brown". Right?

Comment: You are probably making the project harder than it need to be, not to mention it will really search slower.

Comment: Should "dog" match "dogs"? You can join the source table you're searching with the split search terms, group the results by source row, and check the count of distinct search term matches. It is assumed that your search terms never include duplicates, e.g. "dog", "cat', "dog", or confusing choices like "cat", "catapult", "let", "pull", "pullet".

Comment: @SlavaMurygin That's how it's working now. The customer asked for more.

Comment: @Chuck You are absolutely correct. The customer wants it to work that way but I think I'm going to manage expectations and tell them what you just said. Even Google's search doesn't return identical results when identical search terms are in a different order!

Comment: If you want to write similar search as Google has you have to ask for similar budget. Have you look at "Full text Search"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question just from a SQL perspective, Yes, you can join the function to the table (I've gone via a temp table though) and use a [HAVING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause to make sure all search terms are included, something like this.

```
SELECT
    f.Parsed
INTO 
    #s
FROM
    dbo.Split(@terms) f

DECLARE @c INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #s)

SELECT 
    t.ID 
FROM 
    Table t 
        INNER JOIN #s s on t.Description LIKE '%' + s.Parsed + '%'
GROUP BY
    t.ID
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = @c
```

However, as comments to the question allude, this approach to searching leaves a lot of open questions. If you can take a look at SQL Server [Full-Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) - more effort to setup but much better results.

Comment: I think you want a `distinct` in there. What if you search for "cat" and "dog" in "one fish, two fish, red cat, blue cat"? Or "duck" in "duck, duck, duck, goose"? Do both of those test cases include all of the search terms?

Comment: @HABO I think the `GROUP BY` is taking care of uniqueness in the results.

Comment: @CB_Ron Yes, exactly.

Comment: My bad. I was thinking of matching _each_ occurrence of each search term and counting them up. `LIKE` doesn't care about multiple matches and the `INNER JOIN` is only generating one row per description/term pair regardless of the number of matches.